# Bluetooth Server Socket on Unity3d

Tags: c#, sockets, unity-game-engine, bluetooth

I currently have client socket code on visual studio written in c++ that creates a Bluetooth client socket. Previously, I had written code in Java for a Bluetooth server socket and everything was working, but I want to have the server socket on unity so that I can receive data into the Unity application to perform a function. I decided to rewrite the server socket code in C# to use in unity and am using the InTheHand.dll library. Is this doable in Unity? I don't have pro but I understand net libraries can be used in the free version. I am receiving a lot of errors but I am unsure if it is because what I am trying to do is not possible with the free version of Unity or if I'm doing it wrong. Here is the piece of my Code where I try to make the Bluetooth server socket in unity. I have "using InTheHand.Net" and a couple of other includes for the other Bluetooth functionalities :

`Guid UUID = new Guid("0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB");
     bool ServerRunning = false;
     Stream mStream;
     BluetoothListener BTListener = new BluetoothListener(UUID);
     BTListener.Start();
     ServerRunning = true;
     BluetoothClient conn = BTListener.AcceptBluetoothClient();
     mStream = conn.GetStream()`

Comment: Unity5 free version has the same features as pro, so no limit there for using dll's etc. So what kind of error messages you are getting?

Comment: @mgear It says "SocketException: An Address Incompatible with the requested protocol was used" and I think it may have to do with my GUID? The error is pointing to this line of code: `BluetoothListener BTListener = new BluetoothListener(UUID);` and I initialize UUID like so: `Guid UUID = new Guid("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB");`

Comment: Is it possible that I keep the Bluetooth socket on the client side and use a TCPListener on the server side? I am trying, but to no avail